# Unit testing project orleans file not found exception

Tags: c#, orleans

I am trying to get a handle on unit testing a fairly simple application I have made but I am getting a very odd error whilst running the test.

All I did was:

- Created a new class library
- Added references to `Microsoft.Orleans.TestingHost` and `Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansProviders` both version `1.1.2`
- Run the test and get a `file not found exception`

The test file looks like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class HelloWorldTests : TestingSiloHost
{
    //public HelloWorldTests()
    //    : base(new TestingSiloOptions
    //           {
    //               SiloConfigFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\_Foo\Host\Tests\OrleansConfigurationForTesting.xml")
    //           },
    //          new TestingClientOptions
    //          {
    //              ClientConfigFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\_Foo\Host\Tests\ClientConfigurationForTesting.xml")
    //          })
    //{
    //}

    [Test]
    public async Task When()
    {
        var grain = GrainFactory.GetGrain<IHelloGrain>(0);
        var reply = await grain.SayHello("Hello");

        Assert.That(reply, Is.EqualTo("Hello World"));
    }
}
```

^^ From the above I even tried to hard code the config file's location.

Stack Trace (interestingly its looking for the config file in my **appdata folder**:

```
OneTimeSetUp: System.Exception : Exception during test initialization: 
Exc level 0: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Orleans.Runtime.Silo+SiloType,OrleansRuntime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Orleans.TestingHost.TestingSiloHost.LoadSiloInNewAppDomain(String siloName, SiloType type, ClusterConfiguration config, AppDomain& appDomain)
   at Orleans.TestingHost.TestingSiloHost.StartOrleansSilo(SiloType type, TestingSiloOptions options, Int32 instanceCount, AppDomain shared)
   at Orleans.TestingHost.TestingSiloHost.<InitializeAsync>d__16.MoveNext()

Exception doesn't have a stacktrace

OneTimeSetUp: System.Exception : Exception during test initialization: 
Exc level 0: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs12\OrleansConfigurationForTesting.xml'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path)
   at System.IO.File.OpenText(String path)
   at Orleans.Runtime.Configuration.ClusterConfiguration.LoadFromFile(String fileName)
   at Orleans.TestingHost.TestingSiloHost.StartOrleansSilo(SiloType type, TestingSiloOptions options, Int32 instanceCount, AppDomain shared)
   at Orleans.TestingHost.TestingSiloHost.<InitializeAsync>d__16.MoveNext()

Exception doesn't have a stacktrace

OneTimeSetUp: System.Exception : Exception during test initialization: 
Exc level 0: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Orleans.Runtime.Silo+SiloType,OrleansRuntime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Orleans.TestingHost.TestingSiloHost.LoadSiloInNewAppDomain(String siloName, SiloType type, ClusterConfiguration config, AppDomain& appDomain)
   at Orleans.TestingHost.TestingSiloHost.StartOrleansSilo(SiloType type, TestingSiloOptions options, Int32 instanceCount, AppDomain shared)
   at Orleans.TestingHost.TestingSiloHost.<InitializeAsync>d__16.MoveNext()

Exception doesn't have a stacktrace
```

Comment: In visual studio, right click the config file in solution explorer, go to properties and make sure the "Copy to output directory" property **is not set** to "Do not copy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit old, but worth being here...

This is a quirk of NUnit and/or its VS adaptor.

Orleans scans for files in the current directory, but NUnit sets this elsewhere, where none of the intended files live.

You therefore have to set the current directory yourself before Orleans starts up.

Put something like this in the namespace of your tests:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class PreFixture
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetUp() {
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

schizo,

If you are using MSTest framework, just add `[DeploymentItem("missing_file_or_dll_name")]` for each item it is complaining. If you are using xunit, the referenced DLLs should be copied to output directory and all extra files(like the config ones), should be set to "`Copy To Output`".

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: The `TestFixture` attribute implies they're using nunit.